# How to Map rows of same table based on child table values?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, stored-procedures

I need to write SQL that generates a table or view that contains a mapping of one entity to another entity, where the entities belong to the same table, and the mapping conditions are based on their children's values. Say I have the following schema:

[image: Schema Illustration]

I need to be able to creating a mapping between two different Entity IDs (call them A and B) based on the following conditions:

1. The Category.Name value of the Category linked to the Person linked to Entity A must have the same Category.Name value of the Category linked to the Person linked to Entity B ("The validation names of each entity must match")
2. The Verification linked to Entity A must have the same VerificationValue as the Verification linked to Entity B ("The Verification values of the two entities must match")
3. The VerificationType.Name linked to the verification that is linked to Entity A must be the same as the VerificationType.Name that is linked to the Verification that is linked to Entity B ("The verification types of each entity must match")

The end result would be something like this as a TABLE or VIEW:

```
entity_ID_A | entity_ID_B
--------------------------
1             2
3             4
11            10
```

Assume for simplicity's sake that we cannot have more than one value mapped to entity_ID_A

In code, this could be expressed simply as:

```
Entity a, b = //do some stuff to get the two different entities
return a.person.name == b.person.name &&
    a.verification.verificationValue == b.verificationValue &&
    a.verification.verificationType.name == b.verification.verificationType.Name;
```

I'm not even sure where to begin expressing this in SQL, much less generate a table of mappings of entity IDs that meet this criteria. Do I join all of the tables together before doing any comparisons? Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Join all tables at first and then make self-join:

```
with ents as (
    select e.id, c.name cname, v.verificationvalue vval, vt.name vname
      from entity e
      join person p on e.person_id = p.id
      join category c on c.id = p.category_id
      join verification v on v.id = e.verification_id
      join verificationtype vt on vt.id = v.verificationtype_id)
select a.id id_a, b.id id_b
    from ents a
    join ents b on a.id < b.id
               and a.cname = b.cname
               and a.vval = b.vval
               and a.vname = b.vname
```

Comment: Ok, the piece I was missing was the self join at the end. But what is the purpose of `a.id < b.id`?

Comment: To eliminate pairs of same entities (1-1, 2-2...) and to not show them twice (1-2, 2-1, 3-4, 4-3...).